# Sending multiple recipient using smtp mail php

Tags: php, smtp

I am using smtp mail, I would like to send mails to multiple receiver. This is the code that I found several days ago.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"):
$to = "ahmad@polymer.com, dwi.hyuga@gmail.com";
$cc = "";
$from = "prod@polymer.com";
$subject = "Daftar PR Karet";
$body = "
Berikut data PR karet pada tanggal $now :

$y

Note : pesan ini digenerate oleh computer.
Terima Kasih,
            ";
    $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, `$SmtpPass, $from, $to, $cc, $subject, $body);`
    $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
endif;
```

How can I send mail to multiple recipient?
the second email wouldn't sent...

Comment: did you try the code? what is the error? as you can see in the code, `$to = "ahmad@polymer.com, dwi.hyuga@gmail.com"` is multiple recipient.

Comment: but the second email wouldn't sent, and no error shown

Comment: try changing your to to this `$to  = 'ahmad@polymer.com' . ', '; $to .= 'dwi.hyuga@gmail.com';` Also, try checking your junk/spam mail.

Comment: @active92 thank you for your grammar correction,,, I'll try your suggestion...

Comment: @active92, It wouldn't sent

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't send? Gmail has a habit of not receiving suspicious emails (some sort of spam protection). Have you tried sending to multiple non-Gmail addresses?

Comment: yup, I am trying to send it to zoho mail, gmail, my own hosting mail too. and now, if I write more than one email it'll not send both.. if i just write it one email, it'll send perfectly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find my answer by my close friend,

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"):
data = (",", "ahmad@polymer.com,dwi.hyuga@gmail.com");
for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++):
$to = $data[$x];
$cc = "";
$from = "prod@polymer.com";
$subject = "Daftar PR Karet";
$body = "
Berikut data PR karet pada tanggal $now :

$y

Note : pesan ini digenerate oleh computer.
Terima Kasih,
            ";
    $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, `$SmtpPass, $from, $to, $cc, $subject, $body);`
    $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
endfor;
endif;
```